# Remove Response header from jquery.js

Tags: iis, http-headers, iis-8

I have hosted .Net application on IIS and want to hide IIS version from response header. It is working for dot net files with below steps,

1. Open the IIS Manager.
2. Select the Orion website.
   3.Select "HTTP Response Headers"
3. Select the "X-AspNet-Version" HTTP header and select "Remove".

But not working for Jquery.js file

Please help with solution to hide IIS server information ("Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0")

[image: Find attached screenshot]

Comment: you might have to disable it from the whole iis instance

Answer (score 0):

You could try to refer to the steps below that may help you disable the Server header.

1. Select the site in the **IIS**.
2. Go to **Configuration Editor**.
3. Set **Remove Server Header** to **True**.

[image]

4. **Restart** the site in the IIS.
5. Visit the site in the browser and see whether it removed the Server header.